# What is a good way to handle widget placement to account for screen rotation using python / kivy?

Tags: python, widget, kivy, screen-rotation

When I build an application using kivy, I can get everything where I want it, but when I rotate the screen from portrait to landscape, my widgets start colliding with one another. What is a good way to prevent this from happening?

In the attached example, I was able to bind the placement of a settings button to my header label widget, but I was unsuccessful in getting my scrollview to bind to it so when it rotates it stays X amount of space away from the bottom of the label.

Python:

```
class First_Screen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(First_Screen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        list_of_buttons = [
        'button1',
        'button2',
        'button3',
        'button4',
        'button5',
        'button6 ',
        'button7',
        'button8',
        ]

        class My_Grid(FloatLayout, ScrollView):
            grid = ObjectProperty(None)

            def on_grid(self, *args):
                for btn in list_of_buttons:
                    btn = Button(
                        text = btn,
                        )
                    btn.bind(on_press= First_Screen.print_message)
                    self.grid.add_widget(btn)


    def print_message(self):
        print ('Congratulations! You have clicked a button!')

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Stack_Overflow(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager(transition = FadeTransition())
        sc0 = First_Screen(name = 'first_screen')
        sm.add_widget(sc0)
        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Stack_Overflow().run()
```

kv:

```
ScreenManagement:
    First_Screen:

<ImageButton@ButtonBehavior+Image>:


<First_Screen>:
    name: 'first_screen'

    Label:
        id: header
        text: 'header'
        pos_hint: ({'left' : 1, 'top' : 1})
        size_hint: (1,None)
        height: dp(50)
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: (.6, .6, .6, 1)
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

    ScrollView:
        size_hint: (1,.8)
        pos_hint: ({'center_x' : .5, 'center_y' : .5})

        My_Grid:
            grid: grid
            GridLayout:
                id: grid
                cols: 1
                size_hint_y: None
                row_default_height: "40dp"
                height: self.minimum_height



    ImageButton:
        id: settings
        size_hint: None, None
        height: dp(30)
        width: dp(30)
        pos: header.x, header.y + 10
        pos_hint: {'right': 1}
        source: 'settings_black.png'
```

Images: [portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tS3j.png), [landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9Oih.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I misunderstood the question, I thought you were unsatisfied with the `Image`. In the case of `ScrollView` the problem isn't the `ScrollView` itself, because that uses relative positions and sizes.

The problem is the `Label`(header), which has height set as an ***absolute*** number i.e. `50` dense pixels. It means that whatever screen you have or however you size anything else, this widget will have 50 pixels [corrected](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.metrics.html#dimensions) with dpi of the screen.

In reality this means that if your screen reaches `400x100` resolution, your `Label` will take half of the screen and `ScrollView` will be placed on top of that (most likely you won't see the `Label` then).

To fix that you have two options. If you want to play with `FloatLayout` alone, you'll need to use *correct* positioning/sizing i.e. *relative* and make sure widgets aren't overlaping.

Otherwise just drop the widgets to `BoxLayout` or a similar other layout that manages such things on its own:

```
class First_Screen(BoxLayout, Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(First_Screen, self).__init__(orientation='vertical', **kwargs)
```

or a little bit different (and better looking):

```
class First_Screen(BoxLayout, Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
```

and in kv:

```
<First_Screen>:
    name: 'first_screen'
    orientation: 'vertical'
```

Also note, that there's a [`screen` module](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.modules.screen.html), which makes testing such things a way more easier than dropping the code to apk and to android when it's just unnecessary. Example:

```
python main.py -m screen:note2,landscape,scale=.5
```

Comment: My settings button is actually acting exactly how I want it to. I had it setup that way so when I rotate the phone it still stays centered in the middle of the header label. My main problem is I can't figure out how to get my scrollview widget to begin a certain amount of pixels below my header label, and instead when the phone is rotated it collides with the header label, while the settings button stays exactly where it should be. I tried setting the position of my scrollview with header.x and header.y but that didn't seem to be working, and the example I have posted is the closest I could do

Comment: @Indeciski ping

Comment: Putting into a BoxLayout seemed to work well. As far as using a FloatLayout, I noticed that if you create a button then rotate the phone, it tends to get squished and looks awkward. Is this something that is fixed by using RelativeLayout which says it acts like FloatLayout except that its child widgets are positioned relative to the layout, or could you point me towards what documentation I should be looking at so I can check that out as an alternative and see which works better for me?

In any case, many thanks for your help and detailed explanations!

Comment: @Indeciski Well, as you've said, anything that makes positions automatic, so [here](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.layout.html) is the base and the rest it either reading the top of the each layout's page (if it does positions too) or directly the [source code](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/tree/master/kivy/uix/) to see how it behaves. To have some minimal sizes you could use `size_hint_min` and `size_hint_max` for the maximal ones, which may be useful in mobile layouts. Personally, I see no point in using `FloatLayout` on mobile exactly because of the rotating screen, which changes stuff.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know FloatLayout isn't the best option for mobile then, because trying to get that to act right has caused me a lot of headache when clearly there would have been better ways to accomplish what I was trying to do